# unable to perform query using mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["name"]);
    $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["surname"]);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["username"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["email"]);
    $pw1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["pw1"]);

    $query = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('id','name', 'surname', 'username', 'email', 'password') VALUES (NULL,'$name', '$surname', '$username', '$email', '$pw1')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
    if(!$result){
        echo ("fail");
    }
```

I test if the query has worked using if(!$result){ echo ("fail");} and it echoes fail every time and no data is inserted into the database every time! I have checked the syntax and i believe it is correct... could this be because of the database "collation"?

Comment: print out the query and run it manually in the mysql console

Comment: @e4c5 I have copied and pasted 'INSERT INTO 'users' ('id','name', 'surname', 'username', 'email', 'password') VALUES (NULL,'$name', '$surname', '$username', '$email', '$pw1')' into the console and it says i have incorrect syntax

Comment: The generated SQL!

Comment: try removing `'id', `  and NULL  from your insert query. I'll assume it's an auto-increment column, so if you don't specify it at all, it will get the correct value, but yes, you should have code to display a meaningful mysqli error, instead of just "fail"

Comment: Remove single quotes for database tablename and remove column name id and column value null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the single quote at the `table` or `field` name. You have to use a Backtick (like  ``)  which is located in under Esc key or left side of 1 Key or upper side of Tab key. It should looks like:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `username`, `email`, 
`password`) VALUES ('null', '$name', '$surname', '$username', '$email', '$pw1')";
```

or

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname, username, email, 
password) VALUES ('null', '$name', '$surname', '$username', '$email', '$pw1')";
```

**Note:** If your `id` field is already set auto increment then you can remove `id` and value `null`. Because id value will automatically increment.

Hope it will helpful.

Comment: Thank you! Backtick and single quotes are too similar!